# MS Access duplication

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got my query in MS Access duplicating its errors. The data is being entered from a Windows Forms app, and the data is in two separate tables. I'm using a basic query to show each row in the table. Name table and score table.

Now the issue is that the data is duplicating itself.

[Image of the access table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbJpn.jpg)

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT score.score, name.Name
FROM name, score;
```

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QimkB.png)

What SQL code could I use to stop the duplication error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have no join condition in your query, hence this join is working as cross-join. Please use join condition to join these tables.

Comment: it is cross join so you will get n*n records as output.

Comment: you must have a reference column in your score table that refers to name table.

Comment: @HirenPatel how would I do that? Not really sure.

Comment: Please share the table schema.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai how would that SQL code look like.

Comment: @HirenPatel my table doesn't use any relationships but I have added the table schema

Comment: @MahdiDahir, Please post the sample data of both tables.

Comment: Please add a reference key to your score table. that point primary key of name table.

Comment: How would you know which score belongs to which name? You will need some key linking the two (and use that relation in the query)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing what could I use to link the two tables. Would an id work. I'm pretty new to database.

Comment: @mahdi research "Foreign Key" - basically you need to add the ID of the record you refer to, to your base record

Comment: Relating tables with key fields is most basic concept of relational database design. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/introduction-to-relational-databases/. Any introductory tutorial book should cover that in first chapter. You could probably benefit from a solid week with one.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a long integer number field `StudID` in Scores table then do data entry to add the appropriate student identifier value into each Scores record. This will establish a primary/foreign key relationship between tables that can be used in query with a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN on key fields.

This assumes a student can have multiple scores (for what?). If there can be multiple scores, then probably also need a date field `ScoreDate` and then possibly should be a `Subject` field.

If student can have only 1 score, then don't need Scores table - have a field `Score` in Students table.

Strongly advise not to use reserved words as names for anything. `Name` is a reserved word.